# How to retrieve all records from the subgrid?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I was wondering if there was anyway to retrieve the records within a subgrid through JavaScript. I am able to get control of the subgrid, but I can't go further from there.

All the resources I used seemed to use methods that no longer exist. Some of the methods that I tried were get_allRecordIds, getCellValue, getRecordsFromInnerGrid.

Comment: Whoever down voted this without even commenting, thanks for being a dick.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to retrieve records from a subgrid. Though you can use jQuery to do this. You can use "developer tool F12" of IE to see the dom of the page. Generally sugrids are loosely arranged as:

```
<div>
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Col1</td>
         <td>Col2</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

You can write some jQuery code which will read this dom structure and will return you the desired result. I would suggest you to use "developer tool" to get the id of the table or div to be used in jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to let it go. Don't even try to modify the grids view it will drive you in a corner and it will break, also will be unsupported probably. If you need to retrieve all the items go through OData and retrieve them with a REST or a SOAP call.

Comment: I ended up going with OData. Thanks.